# Why does Posts.FavoriteCount column have both Null & 0 values in SEDE?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I found that `FavoriteCount` column in `Posts` table in SEDE contains both `NULL` and `0` values for "questions" (PostType = 1). Why some questions have `Null` instead of `zero`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it has never been set to anything it would usually be `null`.

However, if it was made favourite and then the favourite vote removed, it would end up with a 0 score.

Comment: So I guess that means we can use SEDE to find out if a question has ever been favorited by anyone in the past. I'm not quite sure what to *do* with that information, but I'm sure somebody's curious about it.

Comment: Thanks much! I guess same thing goes for `Posts.Score` cause it also contains both 0 & NULL values.

Comment: @Layray - basically. The SQL columns default to `null` (for a good few columns). If there were writes to it, it would change to a value.